# What is open cost bytes in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

What does this property `spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes` do  ?

This is official document definition:

> The estimated cost to open a file, measured by the number of bytes could be scanned in the same time. This is used when putting multiple files into a partition. It is better to over-estimated, then the partitions with small files will be faster than partitions with bigger files (which is scheduled first). This configuration is effective only when using file-based sources such as Parquet, JSON and ORC.

But still didn't get it. Can anyone explain with small example that why and where its useful?

Comment: Just from the description, it sounds like it's asking you to estimate how many bytes you could read in the time it takes to open a file. "Cost" here is CPU time, not money. It sounds like it would be used to decide whether to spill a partition into a new file: "at what point is the cost of creating that new file worth it, given that we could have used that same CPU time for other I/O work?"

Comment: @yshavit, how it relates to read multiple files from source ?

Comment: Does it mean number of bytes to be read at once ? am confused to understand this property

Comment: I don't know the details, sorry. All I can do is guess from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Open Cost in Bytes is the cost needed to open the file. In Apache Spark, spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes is 4MB. Whatever time and resources are needed to process the 4MB data, is the open cost in bytes.
For example, if we want to open two files of 10 MB each and combine them, it is like